# how to redirect to a new page from servlet

Tags: html, mysql, database, servlets, servlet-3.0

I am sending data to the servlet from `login.html` using JQuery in json format to the servlet and after matching the record i want to open a new page `home.html` and i also want to send the data to `home.html`:

```
DTORegisteration dto=new DTORegisteration();
        public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
        String id = req.getParameter("id");

        String password = req.getParameter("password");
        System.out.println("id "+id);
        System.out.println("password  "+password);
        dto.setId(id);          
        dto.setPassword(password);
        String str=new ServiceRegisteration().getDetails(dto);
        JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
        if(str.equals("success")) {

           try { json.put("welcome", "welcome"); json.put("name",
           DAORegisteration.name); 
           }catch(JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
           pw.print(json);



        }
    }
```

Comment: What about https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-page-redirect.htm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sendRedirect() method of HttpServletResponse interface can be used to redirect response to another resource, that may be servlet, jsp or html file.

```
 if(check your param values here) { // if its as expected
                res.sendRedirect("home.html");
    }
```

Actually 
we cannot send a post request using sendRedirect() method because as per standards redirect should use get.

You can use RequestDispatcher Class to forward() requests with parameters,

e.g.-

```
req.setAttribute("Greetings", "Greeting of day");
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = servletContext().getRequestDispatcher("url");
dispatcher.forward(req, res);
```

Comment: i want to send the user related data at the time of redirecting, is it possible?

Comment: @shahbazusmani since its is useful to you please upvote the answer